# A complicated two dates comparison in swift

Tags: swift, date, unix-timestamp

Building an app that issues queueing system tickets. The user checks the branch he will reserve his ticket in and issues a ticket with a certain delay time. The delay time is the time he will need to reach the branch.

The queueing system API branches database has the opening and closing time fields of the branch in string format as `"9:00"` and `"17:00"`. Also API has a boolean field i use it if branch is closed or open so i check that boolean to not issue tickets if branch status is closed.

The issue is when the branch is open the user will issue a ticket with a certain delay time. What i need to do is to calculate:

```
   var branchClosingTime = "17:00"
   var delay = 3000 //sec
   var timeNow = Date().TimeIntervalSince1970

    if (timeNow + delay) < branchClosingTime {
         print("Issue ticket")
    } else {
       print("Don't issue ticket")
    }
```

By this calculation i will check if he didn't by pass the branch closing time. I have the algorithm in mind but i really don't know how this could be done. I played a little bit in the xcode playground converting dates to unix timestamps but i don't know how to convert this closing time string to a unix timestamp and compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse out the contents of the string using:

```
let dateString = "20:34"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour,.minute], from: date)

    print(components.hour!)
    print(components.minute!)
}
```

The Calendar class has routines that should help you figure out what date (relative to right now) that the string represents.  I don't know, for example, if your "17:00" means today, or the next occurrence of 17:00... but the calendar class has routines to help you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks @Scott yes did the date formate part but didn't check about the calendar Class. I will go deep and check it out. For the "17:00" it will be the next occurrence because the user won't be able to issue ticket before "09:00" because the branch is open status boolean field will be `false` already.

Comment: see `func nextDate(after: Date, matching: DateComponents, matchingPolicy: Calendar.MatchingPolicy, repeatedTimePolicy: Calendar.RepeatedTimePolicy, direction: Calendar.SearchDirection)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Scott's advices i was able to solve my issue and here is how it was done.

```
var orderTime: TimeInterval = 1494520200 - 7200  // -7200 sec to adabt to my time zone

var delay: TimeInterval = 2000 //sec

var orderDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: orderTime) // "May 11, 2017, 4:30 PM"

var orderDateWithDelay = orderDate + delay //"May 11, 2017, 5:03 PM"


let dateString = "17:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour,.minute], from: date)

    let closeDate = calendar.nextDate(after: orderDate, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .forward) //"May 11, 2017, 5:00 PM"


    if closeDate!.compare(orderDateWithDelay) == .orderedDescending
    {
        print("Close date after order date")
        print("Issue ticket")

    } else if closeDate!.compare(orderDateWithDelay) == .orderedAscending {
        print("Close date before order date")
        print("Don't issue ticket")

    } 
}
```